# Find $\frac{dy}{dx},$ if $x\sqrt{1-y}+y\sqrt{1-x}=0$

Tags: implicit-differentiation

If $x\sqrt{1-y}+y\sqrt{1-x}=0$, then show that $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-1}{(1+x)^2} $.

**Attempt:**

On differentiating both sides w.r.t x, I got the following result, which doesn't match with the expected expression.

$$\frac{d}{dx} \{ x\sqrt{1-y} + y\sqrt{1-x} \} = 0$$
$$\frac{dx}{dx}\sqrt{1-y}+x\frac{d}{dx}\{\sqrt{1-y}\}+\frac{dy}{dx}\{\sqrt{1-x}\}+y\frac{d}{dx}\{\sqrt{1-x}\}=0$$
$$\sqrt{1-y}+x\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-y}}\frac{dy}{dx}+\sqrt{1-x}\frac{dy}{dx}+y\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-x}}=0$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}\{x\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-y}}+\sqrt{1-x}\}=-1\times\{\sqrt{1-y}+y\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x-1}}\}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{\sqrt{1-y}+y\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x-1}}}{x\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y-1}}+\sqrt{x-1}}$$

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @Arthur its alright , happens to the best of us

Comment: You have an equation. Just put the value of $\sqrt{1-y}$ from that.

Comment: I can see one small misake: the denominator in the last expression should be $x\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y-1}} + \sqrt{x-1}$. But the biggest thing here is not really a mistake, but rather that you just aren't finished yet: you ought to get rid of your $y$'s.

Comment: @Arthur I have edited the question. I did try getting rid of the $y$ and $\sqrt{1-y}$ from the equation. But you will be left with at least one of $y$ or $\sqrt{1-y}$ in the answer. I think lab bhattacharjee has got the question right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$x\sqrt{1-y}=-y\sqrt{1-x}$$

For real $x,y$ both must have opposite signs.

Squaring both sides $$x^2(1-y)=y^2(1-x)$$

$$0=x^2-y^2+xy(x-y)=(x-y)(x+y+xy)$$

Unless $x=y\implies x=y=0$ $$x+y+xy=0\iff y=?$$

Comment: Thanks! Your answer has taught me a new method of solving derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

$$x\sqrt{1-y}+y\sqrt{1-x}=0$$
Squaring on both sides gives
$$x^2(1-y)=y^2(1-x)$$
Now differentiate and $(uv)^{\prime}=uv^{\prime}+vu^{\prime}$

$$x^2\left(1-\frac{dy}{dx}\right)+2x(1-y)=y^2+2y\frac{dy}{dx}(1-x)$$
$$x^2-x^2\frac{dy}{dx}+2x-2xy=y^2+2y\frac{dy}{dx}-2xy$$
$$x^2-y^2+2x=2y\frac{dy}{dx}+x^2\frac{dy}{dx}$$
$$x^2-y^2+2x=\frac{dy}{dx}(x^2+2y)$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x^2-y^2+2x}{x^2+2y}$$

Comment: Why did you say that $\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x} = x \sqrt{1-y} + y \sqrt{1-x}$?

Comment: It was a typo, I corrected it now, Thanks.